# Mathematics Courses for an Economist

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, statistics, probability-theory

I am an Economist and I am interested in further developing my mathematical knowledge and skills. I would like to get your opinions on the topics that I should cover and which are also important for an Econometrician/Applied Statistician.

For example, I was wondering if doing any advanced Algebra courses would help. Also I thought about Stochastic Calculus or some advanced Differential Geometry, which although I have some knowledge about, I am not entirely confident with.

So far I have completed Courses (at Undergraduate and Masters level in the following areas): 
-Multivariate Calculus (undergraduate)
-Optimization Theory (undergraduate)
-Linear Algebra (masters level) 
-Probability Theory (masters level) -covering topics such as 0/1 Law, modes of convergence, probability measure theory,  following "A Probability Path"
-Real Analysis (masters level - I have not done Functional Analysis, but I did Lebesgue measures and the other topics that are covered in the courses before Functional Analysis)
-Differential Equations (undergraduate) 
(Apart from these I have done some of the most advanced courses in Econometrics offered by my Uni.)

Comment: You might want to see out undergrad and grad programs in mathematical economics and see what the coursework entails. For example: http://economics.sas.upenn.edu/undergraduate-program/mathematical-economics-major/course-requirements. Here is a list of schools which specialize in this area: http://grad-schools.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-humanities-schools/econometrics-rankings. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for that. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: Functional analysis is useful if you're interested in macroeconomics. For example, a lot of Stokey and Lucas can be placed in that context, although they don't, for accessibility reasons. I'd suggest you stay away from algebra, unless you have a very specific interest such as application of homology in social choice theory. Same thing goes for differential geometry.

Comment: Certain parts of econometrics is also functional analytic, e.g. covariance-stationary time series, Wiener-Kolmogorov prediction, spectral analysis should all be done in the context of Hilbert spaces. Depends on how much you need.

Comment: @Michael That's much helpful Michael. Thank you.